# What script font is this?

Tags: fonts, typography, serif

Thought it might be Zapfino but I can't find the T Glyph and the Serifs are slightly different. This is generated from a low resolution image I posted on WhatTheFont.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Edwardian Script ITC" looks very similar:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Interesting that's an exact match. Now I need to ID the other type used with the T, as it appears to be completely different. Thanks again.